# MongoNetworkError: connection XX to myDatabase:27017 closed

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, digital-ocean, replicaset

I'm running node on a DigitalOcean ubuntu droplet and getting this error on the droplet but not when I run the same processes on my machine.  There are a number of questions about this on SO, but most of them have to deal with remote connections whereas my connection is to localhost.

Other details:

- I'm running a replica set
- I'm using Mongoose
- I'm just testing this out so I'm only using the smallest droplet size on DigitalOcean.  Maybe a memory issue?
- I'm also frequently getting a 'Error: write EPIPE' error:

---

```
{ Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:66:16)
    name: 'MongoNetworkError',
    errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
    [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

I can add more details/code, but I'm not sure what else is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at my droplet dashboard in DigitalOcean, I was going over the maximum CPU usage.  I made some changes to make the code more efficient and updated the droplet and the issue appears to be gone.

Interestingly, the dashboard is showing that the droplet's CPU usage is still consistently near 100%, but the upgrade seems to have been enough to do the trick.